# Pivot with Dynamic sql as Parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am not sure if this is the way to go though but I would like to know if there is someway to have a stored procedure and pass in a queries to get the values to pivot. I'm not sure if this is a good idea, so sorry if this is a stupid question, but it would be great to pass in a query instead of hard coding every single pivot you want. I have an example of the pivot Stored Procedure that I have coded. This also includes the grand totals for rows and columns.

Don't know if I should add the code as well?

Hope this makes sense.

**Please see my stored procedure code below:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PivotNoAgentPerc_SP]
AS

DECLARE @columnHeaders VARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @columnHeaders  = COALESCE(@columnHeaders + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(granteddate)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) AS granteddate

                    FROM  ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement AS BondSales
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement_cstm AS BondSalesCSTM ON BondSales.id = BondSalesCSTM.id_c 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.ProvincialArea AS ProvincialArea ON BondSalesCstm.provincial_level_c = ProvincialArea.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts AS accounts_1 ON BondSales.account_id1_c = accounts_1.id  AND accounts_1.deleted = 0
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS ConsultantUser ON BondSales.Assigned_user_id = ConsultantUser.id  AND ConsultantUser.deleted = 0

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.BondSaleApplicationStatus AS BondSalesStatus ON BondSalesStatus.ID = BondSales.applicationstatus

                    WHERE BondSales.deleted = 0

                    AND ProvincialArea.SAD_Province = 'Coastal'
                    AND BondSalesStatus.AuditedStatus = 1
                    AND EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) BETWEEN EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-12) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
) AS B
ORDER BY B.granteddate

/* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @GrandTotalCol =
COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + CAST (granteddate AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(granteddate AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) AS granteddate

                    FROM  ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement AS BondSales
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement_cstm AS BondSalesCSTM ON BondSales.id = BondSalesCSTM.id_c 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.ProvincialArea AS ProvincialArea ON BondSalesCstm.provincial_level_c = ProvincialArea.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts AS accounts_1 ON BondSales.account_id1_c = accounts_1.id  AND accounts_1.deleted = 0
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS ConsultantUser ON BondSales.Assigned_user_id = ConsultantUser.id  AND ConsultantUser.deleted = 0

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.BondSaleApplicationStatus AS BondSalesStatus ON BondSalesStatus.ID = BondSales.applicationstatus

                    WHERE BondSales.deleted = 0

                    AND ProvincialArea.SAD_Province = 'Coastal'
                    AND BondSalesStatus.AuditedStatus = 1
                    AND EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) BETWEEN EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-12) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
) AS B
ORDER BY B.granteddate
SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

/* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @GrandTotalRow = 
COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(granteddate AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(granteddate AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) AS granteddate

                    FROM  ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement AS BondSales
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement_cstm AS BondSalesCSTM ON BondSales.id = BondSalesCSTM.id_c 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.ProvincialArea AS ProvincialArea ON BondSalesCstm.provincial_level_c = ProvincialArea.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts AS accounts_1 ON BondSales.account_id1_c = accounts_1.id  AND accounts_1.deleted = 0
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS ConsultantUser ON BondSales.Assigned_user_id = ConsultantUser.id  AND ConsultantUser.deleted = 0

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.BondSaleApplicationStatus AS BondSalesStatus ON BondSalesStatus.ID = BondSales.applicationstatus

                    WHERE BondSales.deleted = 0

                    AND ProvincialArea.SAD_Province = 'Coastal'
                    AND BondSalesStatus.AuditedStatus = 1
                    AND EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) BETWEEN EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-12) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
)AS B
ORDER BY B.granteddate

/* MAIN QUERY */
DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ')
AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
            FROM
                (SELECT
                    ISNULL(ConsultantUser.user_name,''Total'') AS [Consultant],
                    EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) AS [Month Granted],
                    COALESCE(CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN accounts_1.name = ''No Agent Channel'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL)/COUNT(BondSales.name) AS decimal(5,2)), 0) AS NoAgentPerc

                    FROM  ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement AS BondSales
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ccbsm_ccbsm_salemanagement_cstm AS BondSalesCSTM ON BondSales.id = BondSalesCSTM.id_c 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.ProvincialArea AS ProvincialArea ON BondSalesCstm.provincial_level_c = ProvincialArea.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts AS accounts_1 ON BondSales.account_id1_c = accounts_1.id  AND accounts_1.deleted = 0
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS ConsultantUser ON BondSales.Assigned_user_id = ConsultantUser.id  AND ConsultantUser.deleted = 0

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.BondSaleApplicationStatus AS BondSalesStatus ON BondSalesStatus.ID = BondSales.applicationstatus

                    WHERE BondSales.deleted = 0

                    AND ProvincialArea.SAD_Province = ''Coastal''
                    AND BondSalesStatus.AuditedStatus = 1
                    AND EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate,0) BETWEEN EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-12) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)

                    GROUP BY EOMONTH(BondSales.granteddate, 0), ConsultantUser.user_name
                ) A
            PIVOT
                (
                 SUM(NoAgentPerc)
                 FOR [Month Granted]
                 IN ('+@columnHeaders +')
                ) B
ORDER BY [Consultant]

SELECT * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal

UNION ALL

SELECT ''Grand Total'','+ @GrandTotalRow +', ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0)
FROM #temp_MatchesTotal
DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal'

EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)
```

Sorry if the code is long but I just wanted to show you exactly what I an talking about

Comment: Yes,you can write a stored procedure and fetch the values through pivot table.
even you can have the dynamic SQL Pivot. If you could share for what table you are expecting the Pivot than the question will be more appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this is in procedure and it is working fine. Compare your example to below code

You have to write Dynamic sql query 
Example :

```
  declare @s date 

   declare @e date 

   declare @dates varchar(MAX) 





   set @s=DATEADD(DAY,-1,@startdate)

   set @e=@enddate



   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#DATES') IS NOT NULL  

     DROP TABLE #DATES





   CREATE TABLE #DATES

   (

          ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),

          Date VARCHAR(MAX)

   )



   WHILE (@s<@e)

   BEGIN

          INSERT INTO #DATES (Date) 

          select  CONCAT( '[',DATEADD(DAY ,1, @s),']')

          set @s=DATEADD(DAY ,1, @s)

   END



   SELECT @dates= STUFF((

          SELECT ',' + SPACE(1) + Date



 FROM #DATES

          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

          --AS [Dates]



   ------------------------Getting RDW Datewise--------------------------------------

   declare @queryRDW VARCHAR(MAX)

   set @queryRDW='

   select * from (

                 SELECT SUM(RecordValue)/60 RecordValue,RecordType ,Computationdate ,t2.ProjectResourceId,t1.ResourceCode,t1.ResourceName

                 FROM   tblProjectResource t1 INNER JOIN  tblDeploymentWorkbook t2 on t1.ProjectResourceId=t2.ProjectResourceId

                 WHERE 

                        RecordType=''RDW'' and t2.SubCategoryId IN (1) 

                 GROUP BY 

                       RecordType, Computationdate,t2.ProjectResourceId,t1.resourceCode,t1.ResourceName

                 HAVING 

                       Computationdate >= '''+Cast(@startdate as varchar)+''' and Computationdate <= '''+Cast(@enddate as varchar)+'''

   )tab

   PIVOT(

          SUM(RecordValue) for ComputationDate in  ( '+@dates+')

   )t

   Order By ResourceName

   '

   exec (@queryRDW)
```

Comment: It looks pretty much like what I have done. I would like that part to be like a parameter so that I can pass in a query. 99% of the time I will also have the same columns headers (months). The calculated fields and the Rows will be the ones that would change.

Comment: your column must be formatted with [] square  brackets, Print your query

Comment: When I print the query then its the way it should be. There is nothing wrong with the SP I wrote. PIVOT( SUM(NoAgentPerc) FOR [Month Granted] IN ([2017-08-31], [2017-09-30], [2017-10-31] etc) B I only want to know how to use the same SP but then pass a different query that uses other values in order to make up the query and pivot that data. I came across a SP, but its a bit advanced. I am not sure how to execute the SP. [link] (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139391/dynamic-parameters-in-pivot/216021#216021)

Comment: Just understood your problem and updated the code. Now this will work for you ! You can pass @s and @e from your parameters   :)

Comment: This looks amazing. I just don't fully understand what you mean though. Not sure where I should use my code. I'm still a beginner with SP's. I will try and figure it out and then I will get bank to you :)

Comment: when you looked at the link did you look at the last answer? That is similar to what I need. I have exactly what I need for the Pivot. The Grant total column and the grant total rows as well as the dynamic date headers. What I want to do now is pass in a different query (Lets say different calculation fields and a different ResourceName). That example in the link shows how you can pass in a query when you exec the SP.